# PHP Xml-RPC array and struct

Tags: php, xml-rpc

I am using XML-RPC Lib for PHP to use online signature.

This is the official doc :

```
$doc = array(
      "content" => new xmlrpcval($doc_content, "base64"),
      "name" => new xmlrpcval($doc_name, "string")
);

$language = "fr";
$signers = array(new xmlrpcval($signer, "struct"));

$request = array(
    "documents" => new xmlrpcval(array(new xmlrpcval($doc, "struct")), "array"),
    ...
```

But now I want to put several documents in the request. Here is my code :
    $docs = array();

```
foreach ($documents as $document)
{
    // Signature field
    $field = array(
        'page'  => new xmlrpcval($document->page, 'int'),
        'x'     => new xmlrpcval($document->x, 'int'),
        'y'     => new xmlrpcval($document->y, 'int'),
        'label' => new xmlrpcval($document->nom, 'string'),
    );        

    // Document
    $docs []= new xmlrpcval(array(
        'content'   => new xmlrpcval($document->content, 'base64'),
        'name'      => new xmlrpcval($document->nom, 'string'),
        'signatureFields'   => new xmlrpcval($field, 'array'),
    ),'struct');
}

$request = array(
    'documents'     => new xmlrpcval($docs, 'array'),
```

And I catch this error :

> Message: Call to a member function serialize() on a non-object

Does someone allready used this library ? Cause I am lost right now..

Answer (score 1):

I have come to realise that even if we have an array still for using the `phpxmlrpc` library, we need to define the array individually, so if one has to pass an array here is what can be done,

```
    $listids // this was my one dimensional array
    $subs_list_array = array(); 
       foreach ($listids as $id) {
         $subs_list_array[] = new xmlrpcval($id, "int");
    }

    $msg = new xmlrpcmsg(
            "contact.subscribe", array(
              //Set user id
              new xmlrpcval($registration_id, "int"),
              new xmlrpcval($subs_list_array, "array")// <- Now I am able to use the array
            )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

For recursive encoding of php arrays, you can also use the `php_xmlrpc_encode` function that will recursively convert arbitrarily deep data structures